# Hawt.io prevents Jvisualvm to connect to the JVM

Tags: apache-camel, rmi, jmx, jvisualvm, hawtio

I am using Hawt.io to monitor my Apache Camel java app, but I have found that if I let it run I cannot use jvisualvm (and similar tools) to profile my app. It seems Hawt.io is using the connector that Camel exposes so jvisualvm cannot connect to the jvm.

What can I do to have Hawt.io and still be able to use jvisualvm?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Can JConsole connect to your JVM too?

Hawtio just connects to Jolokia on the server side; which just exposes JMX over HTTP/JSON; so the hawtio console doesn't itself change JMX in any way.

Incidentally are you using Local connector to connect from the hawtio web app into a separate JVM? Only that approach does add a jolokia agent dynamically to the JVM you are trying to connect to. If thats whats causing the issue - don't use it - and just configure your own [Jolokia agent](http://jolokia.org/agent.html) in your JVM?

Comment: Tried using jconsole to connect to the JVM.  Doesn't work either.  We are embedding hawtio inside our stand alone java application using http://hawt.io/getstarted as an example to work from.